# Missing Open context option for multiple MP3 files

Tags: windows-7, mp3, context-menu

When multiple MP3 files are selected in Windows Explorer on windows 7 there is no Open option. I have an Open and Edit option via the [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/). This has *nothing* to do with the "Open with" sub-menu. How do I restore the context option when multiple files are selected?

[image: Missing Open Context on Multiple MP3 Files]

Comment: How many are you selecting? There is a 15 limit in W7

Comment: @Moab 19...okay, I'll edit my question to increase the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Registry Editor and create a new DWORD. Keep in mind when I set it to 32 it worked with 38 so I'm not sure if there is a way to set a limit above 15.

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

Name : MultipleInvokePromptMinimum
Type : DWORD
Default : 15 (decimal)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2022295/context-menus-are-shortened-when-more-than-15-files-are-selected

---

Because *someone* is going to feel the need to point out that opening lots of files is inherently a bad thing all the time ever without exception here are some reasons why people want to open lots of files simultaneously:

- Printing multiple items.
- Queuing multiple songs in a media player such as Winamp.
- People will open all the files and work with them until they're all closed and then move them to a different / sub folder.

Comment: if you set the value to 16, this is interpreted by Windows as unlimited.